# Pyramid Framework disallows JSONP callback format of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pyramid

The pyramid web framework disallows AngularJS JSONP callbacks since newer versions (worked in 1.5.3, fails in 1.5.6) throwing the error '400 Invalid JSONP callback function name.' when used with AngularJS (V1.2.28), which passes the callback like this: ptth://example/?callback=angular.callbacks._0

What would be a workaround?

There seem to be no good options to fix this on either the AngularJS (does not allow changing the callback structure) or the Pyramid side.

https://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/master/_modules/pyramid/renderers.html
JSONP_VALID_CALLBACK = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]+$")

```
from pyramid.renderers import JSONP
config.add_renderer('jsonp',JSONP(param_name='callback'))
```

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/1644

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the regex in Pyramid does not allow a dot (.) in the callback name:

```
JSONP_VALID_CALLBACK = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]+$")
```

A workaround for this would be to subclass `pyramid.renderers.JSONP`, override its `__call__` method and make it use a corrected regex. Then you can register your custom renderer with `pyramid.config.Configurator.add_renderer` and use it instead of Pyramid's built-in renderer.

When the problem is fixed in Pyramid, you'll just remove your subclass and use the stock Pyramid renderer. Good on you for lodging a bug report :)

Comment: A monkeypatch works quicker: pyramid.renderers.JSONP_VALID_CALLBACK = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z._$]+$") but it is fixed and backported already.